# Compatibility issue of Netbeans 6.9.1 with Ruby 2.1 and rails 4.1.12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, netbeans, upgrade

I have an application functioning well in the versions Ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.1.1 respectively. I now need to upgrade these to Ruby 2.1 and rails 4.1.12. I am working on windows OS using IDE Netbeans 6.9.1. The application runs fine. But when i try to use the debugger, it prompts me saying it needs a fast debugger, and doesn't work with a slow one. When i try to install it, it fails saying

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe mkrf_conf.rb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.9 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.9/gem_make.out
```

The attempts i have made are;
1. Checked the compatibility of Ruby n rails versions with Netbeans. Can't find a concrete answer.
2. The gem mentioned in the error log, that is ruby-debug-ide seems to be incompatible with the upgraded versions. I have repeatedly tried installing the gem,but it always fails in the IDE.
3. I have been trying to use **ByeBug** but netbeans won't let me try and debug the app. Everywhere i read it says, Byebug is the preferred gem for debugging ruby > 2.0. But netbeans won't let me use it. 
4. I have also considered the option of upgrading my netbeans, but i read that netbeans has removed the support for ROR from further versions. They offer some plugins, but do not guarantee anything.
Prior to the upgrading process, the gems i used for debugging were; gem linecache19', gem 'ruby-debug-base19x', '~> 0.11.30.pre4', gem 'ruby-debug19'. These are not compatible with ruby >2 
I have encountered several questions with this kind of error, but none of them somehow had the exact same situation and hence were of no help.
Also i would like to add, i have installed Ruby from a Ruby installer for windows and DevKit is installed correctly as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came out to be minor issue. To run the Fast Debugger in Netbeans, one needs to install the version >0.4 of the gem ruby-debug-ide.
Worked for me with the version **ruby-debug-ide 0.4.33**